# c# , How to read text file and append it in another text file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

HI can any one help me how to read from text file and append those in another text file.

```
File 1
line1
line2
line3

file2
line4
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? (Hint: you can do this with two method calls using the `File` class...)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. And msdn on system.io.file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not show any effort before asking the community for help.

Comment: `var secondContent = File.ReadAllText("second_file_name");
File.AppendAllText("main_file_name", secondContent);`

Comment: Thanks! done with the file class.and just wanted to know whether the file when appending can be created with the duplicate data, which we have already copied!.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution that minimizes memory consumption which is good for working with very large files.

```
using(var writer = File.AppendText(@"path\to\file2.txt"))
{
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(@"path\to\file.txt"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

See also [`File.AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx).

Comment: This can be further reduced to: `File.AppendAllText(@"path\to\file2.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"path\to\file1.txt"));`, the foreach isn't really necessary in this case.

Comment: That works well for small files, but memory consumption grows with file size.